# Can the endorsing peer see the transient data passed to its chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to pass sensitive data of clients to the chaincode function as given in the [private data example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-private-data) of Hyperledger Fabric. The [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data-arch.html) recommends to pass sensitive data as `--transient` data field and parse the transient map in the [chaincode function execution](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/29ff95e2c6200677b2bc0d4cad647ebff058ebb9/asset-transfer-private-data/chaincode-java/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/samples/privatedata/AssetTransfer.java#L248):

```
    @Transaction(intent = Transaction.TYPE.SUBMIT)
    public Asset CreateAsset(final Context ctx) {
        ChaincodeStub stub = ctx.getStub();
        Map<String, byte[]> transientMap = ctx.getStub().getTransient();
        if (!transientMap.containsKey("asset_properties")) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("CreateAsset call must specify asset_properties in Transient map input");
            System.err.println(errorMessage);
            throw new ChaincodeException(errorMessage, AssetTransferErrors.INCOMPLETE_INPUT.toString());
        }
        byte[] transientAssetJSON = transientMap.get("asset_properties");
        final String assetID;
        final String type;
        final String color;
        int appraisedValue = 0;
        int size = 0;
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new String(transientAssetJSON, UTF_8));
            Map<String, Object> tMap = json.toMap();
            type = (String) tMap.get("objectType");
            assetID = (String) tMap.get("assetID");
            color = (String) tMap.get("color");
            if (tMap.containsKey("size")) {
                size = (Integer) tMap.get("size");
            }
            if (tMap.containsKey("appraisedValue")) {
                appraisedValue = (Integer) tMap.get("appraisedValue");
            }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            String errorMessage = String.format("TransientMap deserialized error: %s ", err);
            System.err.println(errorMessage);
            throw new ChaincodeException(errorMessage, AssetTransferErrors.INCOMPLETE_INPUT.toString());
        }
        //input validations
```

By definition, `transient` data gets excluded from the channel transaction and kept in a transient data store of a peer.

But are the transient fields protected against the endorsing peer itself?

Can the endorsing peer (who is the host of the chaincode) see transient data or possibly parse it?

If yes, what are some of the best practices to hide such sensitive from the endorsing peer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the endorsing peer can see transient data within a transaction proposal that it receives. Best practice is to only send proposals containing private data to peers belonging to organisations that should be able to see that private data.

If you are using Hyperledger Fabric v2.4+ and the [Fabric Gateway](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gateway.html) client APIs, this is taken care of for you. If you are using an older version of Fabric or continuing to use the [legacy SDKs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sdk_chaincode.html), you may need to explicitly specify the endorsing organisations or peers.

Just one other clarification is that the transient data itself is not stored anywhere. If the transaction function writes that transient data to a private data collection then the written data is recorded in that private collection, stored only on peers of organisations that are members of the collection. Similarly, if the transaction function writes any of that transient data to the ledger or returns it in the transaction response, those values will be recorded on the ledger when the transaction is committed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think about fabric-private-chaincode? Is it considered to be a part of future releases in Fabric?

Comment: I don't know much about it, other than that a Fabric RFC for it has been accepted and the prototype repository looks to be active. I don't see it mentioned in the 2022 roadmap for Fabric, but that doesn't necessarily mean it couldn't happen: https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/TSC/2022+Q1+Hyperledger+Fabric